# Updating Websphere Jython results in ImportError

Tags: python, import, module, websphere, jython

I am trying to update the jython version that comes shipped with Websphere 7 by replacing **$WAS_HOME/AppServer/optionalLibraries/jython/** with jython 2.5.2.The jython 2.5.2 is already installed in a different location and is working correctly. When I load the ws admin tool with a simple script jython is unable to find a module within the same directory. For example two scripts in $SCRIPTS_HOME/test:

hello.py :

```
    import bye
    print "Hello, World!"
```

bye.py:

```
    print "bye, World!"
```

Running the hello.py script results in:

*WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "hello.py"; exception informati
on: com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: exception from Jython:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named bye*

Reverting jython back the script runs fine.

By [default Jython should be looking in it's own registry (python.path) which is the working directory in which the script is run from](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21268538) so it should be working. Even passing in the current directory as **-Dpython.path=$SCRIPTS_HOME/test/** doesn't work.